# New Windows 7 install

Tags: windows-7

My daughter has a Lenovo ideapad z565 that I am trying to re-install Windows 7 on. Some of the number keys stopped working and I was told it was probably a virus of some kind. None of my virus software was able to locate or quarantine anything so I wiped the hard drive and tried to re-install Windows 7.

On start up the computer boots from the CD and loads some files. After loading the files Windows tries to start. Then the system restarts and the Windows 7 starts loading the start up files again, then Windows tries to start again, but restarts again. **It's a never ending cycle**.

It never gets to the point where the Windows program actually starts to install the OS. **What am I doing wrong and how can I install a clean copy of Windows 7?**

Comment: This is just guesswork without examining the laptop, but 1) Try to clean the whole disk, reboot and then reinstall (Shift-F10, diskpart, clean). 2) Does it always fail at the same place in the cycle.  3) Does the same DVD work on another computer (e.g. test ina VM), or does another win7 DVD work. (in case your source is damaged).

Answer (score 1):

Is your BIOS or firmware set to always boot off the CD if one is inserted?  Try taking the CD out when you see the Lenovo screen on reboot.

If the installer is crashing while copying files (you'd see a bit of the Windows BSOD), you may have a hardware issue with your optical or hard drive.  If there was a corruption or incomplete copy issue with the CD I believe the installer would fail with a message rather than spontaneously reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have hardware problems, then if computer asks to push a button to boot from CD after you do the initial load, don't, let it boot from the hard disk.  Or, after the intial load, on the restart, go into the BIOS and change your boot order to boot from hard disk first.

Do you have another computer?  The laptop drives are standard SATA connectors these days.  You could try to put the drive in another computer and load on that computer and see if you can reproduce the problem.  If you can, it is the drive or the CD, if you cannot, it is a boot order or hardware problem.

Also, you could download a Linux distribution (free and legal) and try to install that.  If the install goes good, it probably is not a hardware problem.  You can wipe your drive after the Linux install completes (if it does).

FInally, highly unlikely but possible you have a rootkit virus.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit.  Again, I would guess this is NOT the issue, but it can be.  There are rootkit virus scanners out there though.

Answer (score 0):

From what you said

> After loading the files Windows tries to start. Then the system restarts and the Windows 7 starts loading the start up files again

I guess, the issue is with your **Hardisk**, After loading installation files, the setup tries to access the hardisk and will get restarted if there is any issues with hardisk.
Before going for a re installation try to

1.Run chkdsk with all partitions using a third party bootable disk, I suggest rather than going for a third party tool,use a windows xp bootable disk (If you have a Windows XP CD, you can boot from that and when it prompts you, press R to enter recovery mode, you will get a cmd window)

2.wipe off all partitions using a third party software and then try to install operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a oneKey button? if so you can try the lenovo recovery option,

follow the steps here
[Service Manual](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Lenovo/IdeaPad-Z560/Manual/117744)

it's at page 23 of the manual or 26/90 of the whole document